# Comment « relever de » a-t-il glissé sémantiquement à signifier « dépendre de quelqu'un/quelque chose » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [ [TLF :](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/relever) ] B. − Qqn/qqc. relève de qqn/qqc.
>   1. [Le suj. désigne une pers., un attribut d'une pers. ou un territoire] Être subordonné à quelqu'un/quelque chose, dépendre de quelqu'un/quelque chose. [...]
>
> 2. Le plus souvent dans un *cont. admin.* ou *judiciaire*.
>      Être de la compétence, du ressort (de quelque chose).
> 3. Être du domaine de quelqu'un/quelque chose, appartenir (à quelqu'un/quelque chose).
>
> [ [Etymonline :](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/relever) ] [...] from Old French *relever* "to raise, relieve" (11c.) and directly from Latin *relevare* "to raise, alleviate, lift up, free from a burden," from *re-*, intensive prefix (see [re-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=re-&allowed_in_frame=0)), + *levare* "to lift up, lighten," from *levis* "not heavy" (see [lever](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lever&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> The notion is "to raise (someone) out of trouble." From c. 1400 as "advance to the rescue in battle;" also "return from battle; recall (troops)." Meaning "release from duty" is from early 15c. [...]

L'étymon latin explique et partage les autres sens de « relever » que je comprends et donc que je ne cite pas ci-dessus. Pourtant, je ne perçois pas le glissement vers les sens ci-dessus.

Answer (score 2):

Ma lecture de l'étymologie du [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/relever) est que le glissement s'est fait à partir du sens de relever comme "libérer quelqu'un d'un engagement".

La dépendance hiérarchique est alors vue comme une libération : relever de quelqu'un (être sous sa responsabilité), c'est aussi être relevé de sa propre responsabilité

L'ordre chronologique de l'étymologie correspond (1549 pour "libérer quelqu'un", 1573 pour "etre dans la dépendance de") , mais l'origine du glissement sémantique n'est pas attestée

exemple :

> l'armée relève la population de l'obligation de se défendre des invasions  ( au sens de "libérer quelqu'un d'un engagement")

a pu glisser en :

> la charge de la défense des invasions est relevée par l'armée

puis :

> la charge de la défense des invasions relève de l'armée

Comment: **1. I don't understand your answer at all.  Kindly elaborate?**  "La dépendance hiérarchique est alors vue comme une libération : relever de quelqu'un (être sous sa responsabilité), c'est aussi être relevé de sa propre responsabilité". **2. Please simplify and translate this to English? Here's my attempt — Hierarchical dependence is thus viewed as a liberation : relieving someone (being under his responsibility) is also being relieved of his responsibility**?

Comment: Indeed,  "relever", can be synonym of "relieve" in the sense of "take over from". Thus saying "relever de"  can be linked to this sense of the word :  When we put the police in charge of maintaining order,  we can say that the population has been relieved by the police from the hassle of maintaining order. This is the meaning of this answer :   the sense of "relever"  in  "Le maintien de l'ordre relève de la police" can have been progressive starting from this sense of relieve. This interpretation is consistent with what appears in etymological dictionaries but is not explicitly stated in them

Comment: Merci pour l'élaboration! **3. How would you translate your "La dépendance hiérarchique est alors vue comme une libération : relever de quelqu'un (être sous sa responsabilité), c'est aussi être relevé de sa propre responsabilité." to English?** **4. Kindly limelight the "glissement sémantique" even more? Please make it more explicit?**

Comment: **5. Where does "dépendre de » enter the scene in your examples? Can you limelight the "glissement sémantique" even more? Here are my translations —**  The army relieves the population of the obligation to defend itself from invasions.  The charge/onus of the defense from invasions is relieved by the army.  The charge/onus of defense from invasions depends on the army.

Comment: 3. I believe an english translation would not work because my sentence explains how a passive form "être relevé par" can mean the same thing than "relève de", which is not the case in english.     4.  Basically it's like if the expression "I am relieved by x on the task y"  became after lots of usage over the years "the task y now relieves from x".  So it's when the passive form becomes active that "relieves from"  takes the meaning of "depend on"